# Basin Waste Pipe UK

Tags: bathroom

I stripped a sink out with the plan to re-use as much as the old waste fittings as possible, yet as I am building a bulkhead for pipe concealment, I'd like to extend the waste.

In particular, instead of simply connecting the trap/p-pipe back into the original compression fitting, I'd like to bring the trap out by the depth of the new bulkhead.

Would it be possible for someone to attach a link to the necessary extension part I would need to connect these two ends please, with ~200mm horizontal extension.

All help would be appreciated. UK-size basin waste, inch 1/4, standard p-pipe/trap. Photos attached.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Need a better pic of your P-trap connector (the one facing us at the end of the elbow).  Is it another compression connector?

Comment: Hi @Husemann, thanks for getting back to me. Yeah, the p-trap is threaded for the compression nut

Comment: Looks like you need a double slip joint extension tube.  If you can't find one the right length (short enough) you could get a long one, cut out the middle, and reconnect the ends with a shielded Fernco type connector.  YMMV depending on local plumbing codes, of course.